# How to save build time when the configuration change?

Tags: c, makefile

Consider a project of hundred of C files that can be built in different configurations.

A configuration can be distinguished with an additionnal `-D` sent to the compiler *i.e.* `-DHARDWARE_FOO` or `-DHARDWARE_BAR`. When the configuration change I usually need to clean all the objects files by doing this:

```
make clean all
```

Otherwise `make` won't rebuild the project because none of the dependencies have changed.

The trivial solution to avoid cleaning the project manually would be to use a text file named `configuration` that contains the name of the current configuration. In the `Makefile` we will find:

```
%o:%c $(CONFIGURATION) 
   $(cc) -c $< -o $@ -D$(shell cat $(CONFIGURATION))
```

Unfortunately this will still require to rebuild the whole project everytime the configuration change.

I feel this solution can be optimized if I am able to tell make to only rebuild the files that depend on the declaration `$(CONFIGURATION)` *i.e.* `HARDWARE_xxx`.

This could save a lot of time especially when the number of different hardwares is large. In my specific case I am talking about an embedded firmware that can run on different hardware platforms. An hardware platform is identified by a define sent to the compiler. So in the sources we will find plenty of `#ifdef ... #elif ... #endif` directives

My initial thoughts regarding this question was to use a script `getdependencies` that will check all the C files (with their includes) recusively in order to identify which ones depend on the configuration.

So in the `Makefile` I will find:

```
-import configurations.d
configurations.d: configuration
    getdependencies --configuration=$< $(SRCS)
```

I made some research on this to see if a similar solution already exist because I don't want to reinvent the wheel. Unfortunately I did not find anything like this.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the standard way in this case is to define in the `makefile` a target for each configuration and configure the tools (compiler, linker, librarian, assembler, resource builder/compilers etc) create the files they produce into a separate directory for each configuration (use the configuration name as the directory name).

This change brings a side-effect improvement for your build routine: you can build a configuration by simply running `make` with the associated target in the command line (no more file changes). The major improvement is, however, the fact that the compiler will recompile only the files that are modified (because the configurations do not share object and executable files any more).

Comment: Actually this is what I currently have. The side effect of this solution is the cost of the initial build that is done each time I move on another Git branch. Because the branches are quite different and because my Makefile is not robust enough, I need to start from a clean base. If I  want to validate that the changes I made on one configuration will build on all the others, I will need to rebuild all the objects files for each configuration. So in this case your solution is not a solution.

Comment: You said *"Otherwise make won't rebuild the project because none of the dependencies have changed."*. Maybe I didn't understand correctly your problem. What exactly do you mean by a "configuration"? Is it a file? Then add it as a dependency for the files it affects. You can do this by grouping the source files that depend on a configuration in a separate directory (to avoid having a big list of file names in the `makefile`). Then you can put a dependency rule of all the `C` files in that directory on the that specific configuration file.